# Any way to make a React presentational component react to MobX store changes

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have a React table component that gets its data via a prop called `TableStore`. This prop is a high-level abstraction for getting row data:

```
interface TableStore<RowType> {
    getRowIds: () => Array<RowId>;
    getRow: (rowId: RowId) => RowType | undefined;
}

interface MaterialTableProps<RowType> {
    tableStore: TableStore<RowType>;
}

function MaterialTable<RowType>(props: MaterialTableProps<RowType>) {
    ...
}
```

As you can see `MaterialTable` is not a MobX observer. It is part of a component library that is not dependent on MobX.

When I use this component in my app, I supply it a MobX-based TableStore. I would like the table component to re-render whenever the MobX-based store changes:

```
<MaterialTable tableStore={orderStore} />
```

However that does not happen because the table component is not a MobX observer. Is there any way to force the table component to re-render? For example, I am able to force a re-render by dereferencing the store in the parent component (using a simple `console.log()`). But this feels like a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question....

I looked at several options but all of them were kludgy. I finally decided to rework the props of the table component to pass in an array instead of an abstract `TableStore` interface (which the table component can't react to). This allowed me to refrain from adding MobX as a dependency to the table component library while still leverage MobX in the parent component. In summary, the parent component now watches the MobX store, reacts to changes by creating a new array and passing it to the table component.

Here's the new interface for the table component:

```
export interface MaterialTableProps<T extends Entity> extends TableProps {
    entityList: Array<T>;
}

export function MaterialTable<T extends Entity>(props: MaterialTableProps<T>) {
    ...
}
```